# VueJS - Computed property has no setter (but actually has)

Tags: vue.js

I have a component with the name `Wrapper` that wraps another third party component. It looks like this:

```
<template>
  <custom-element
    v-model="computedProperty"
  >
  </custom-element>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    modelName: String
  },
  computed: {
    computedProperty() {
      return this[this.modelName]
    },
    foo: {
      get() {
        // getter logic
      },
      set(value) {
        // setter logic
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When using this element with the code `<wrapper modelName="foo" />` I get this vue warning `Computed property "computedProperty" was assigned to but it has no setter.` It is correct that `computedProperty` has no setter but when using the component with `modelName` set to `foo` it actually should take the setter of the `foo` property. Is this not possible?

Comment: Instead of trying to make it work like you are by using references to other things, try to refactor your logic. Maybe you don't need a `v-model` in this instance (which should be used with a variable defined in `data()` or directly with a getter / setting computed properties) but rather want to use a method bound to `@input`. I would advise against what you trying to currently do for the sake of your sanity, and the sanity of others trying to understand whats going on in your code later on.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that the third party component has some bug. When using `:value` and `@input` the component is not working properly, but only if a `v-model` is provided.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at their source code and seeing if they used custom events possibly: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model  and maybe try hooking into those. If that's not a possibility, the next best option might be to use a dummy variable (just a regular one defined in `data()` )  for the v-model and then using a watcher: https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers to watch it's value and trigger things that way.

Comment: You were right. For that third party component I have to use `:model` and `@change`.

Comment: Cheers! Glad that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to make it work like you are by using references to other things, try to refactor your logic. Maybe you don't need a v-model in this instance (which should be used with a variable defined in data() or directly with a getter / setting computed properties) but rather want to use a method bound to @input.

For components that use custom events and values for binding to v-model:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model

For watching data and reacting to model changes:
https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers